# Can I find snippets using yasnippet for the mode of an org-babel block (e.g. python / bash)?

Tags: org-babel, yasnippet

I like snippets. I use yassnippet a lot. I also use [babel](https://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/babel/) in [org mode](https://orgmode.org/). I would quite like to be able to use my snippets in org babel blocks, but they don't work because I am in the wrong mode.  Is there a way to make them work?

I am aware that there are plugins for multiple modes in the same buffer. Are these compatible with babel?

Comment: FYI all my snippets expand according to the block mode. BTW I'm using Emacs 30, Org 9.6.15, and YASnippet version 20240215.1909.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a folder named `org-mode` in your snippets directory. Yasnippet will allow you to expand all the snippets it contains when you write in `org-mode` code blocks. Then, you can create symbolic links for the snippets you want to use in your code blocks in this `org-mode` snippets directory.

If all the snippets you want to use are all in the same directory, you can directly create a symbolic link named `org-mode` to that directory.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The problem is that I define python snippets while using python - but then I want to use them in a python block in babel.

Comment: Does Yasnippet prompt you for a file to save your Python snippet in when using `yas-new-snippet` ? If it does, then you can create a directory where you save theme all. Then you can create a symbolic link as I suggested before.